# find the row which has the highest sequence number in a table for a specific ID that is in another Table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm have 2 tables:

```
Table 1:
Job #
XLG24
ABC123
XYZ123
```

Table 2:

```
Sequence #  Job # Display Order
1           XLG24    1
2           XLG24    2
2           ABC123   1 
3           ABC123   2 
4           ABC123   3
4           XYZ123   1
```

I am trying to pull the Job # and Sequence # that are found in Table 1 from Table 2. however, when i try it only pulls the job #s found in Table 1 that have the highest sequence # (in this case only Sequence # 4).

This is my code:

```
select * from TABLE2 where JOB# IN
     (SELECT JOB# FROM table1)
      and SEQUENCE# = (select max (SEQUENCE#) from Table2)
order by Display_order desc
```

The output of my code is like this:

```
Sequence #  Job #
4           ABC123
4           XYZ123
```

I want it to look like:

```
Sequence #  Job #
2           XLG24
4           ABC123
4           XYZ123
```

So in summary, I am trying to only find the row which has the highest sequence number in Table 2 for a specific ID that is in Table 1
Can someone please give any advice?

Comment: Is the data you've shown correct? How is ABC123 being included in your output when it doesn't appear in Table 1? It's unclear how you expect to get the desired results based on the sample data. And nor is it clear why - what is the significance of those 3 rows? Are you saying you want to match only the row which has the highest sequence number **for that specific job ID**? If so, then please say so specifically. You haven't really mentioned it, although possibly your title alludes to it (less than clearly, I would say).

Comment: Note#1 table1 contains duplicates. Note#2 `order` is a keyword in SQL, it is unwise to use it as a (column) name.

Comment: @ ADYSON, sorry I made a mistake but yes, ABC123 is in Table1 I just carelessly omitted it.and Yes, I am trying to only find the row which has the highest sequence number in Table 2 for a specific ID that is in Table 1.

Comment: What is your PRIMARY KEY? See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `table1` has unique entries (job number only shows up once), and `table2` has multiple entries (I'm sure these are both just example names for this post), then I think you want to join `table1` to `table2` and then find the max.. like so:

```
SELECT t1.job# jobNum,max(t2.Sequence#) maxSeq 
FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.job#=t2.job#
```

This will include all entries in `table1` - even if they're not found in `table2` - if not found in `table2` then `maxSeq` will contain `NULL`.  If all entries are in both tables, or you only want all entries found in both, you'll want an [`INNER JOIN`](https://www.sqltutorial.org/sql-inner-join/) instead.